# Pass Array Data from One Page to Other page without using $_GET, $_POST,$_SESSION,$_COOKIE, or Javascript LocalStorage

Tags: php

Well I am  given a problem, & need to find a solution to pass data from one page to other page in php , without using

`$_GET`
 `$_POST`
 `$_SESSION`
 `$_COOKIE`

Javascript not allowed

Is there any way out from here or not?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use those methods ?

Comment: Data persistence. How about a file or database?

Answer (score 1):

That is a quite weird question.
**`Below is an alternate "ugly" way that works.`**

`Page1.php`

```
<?php
$var="page1value";
file_put_contents('somefile.txt',$var);
header("location:page2.php");
```

`Page2.php`

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('somefile.txt'); // "prints" page1value
```

Answer (score 1):

Very much simple put all the data to a database and retrieve it from all pages :)

and it will also be more secure and faster way to handle large data.

Answer (score 0):

If "other page" means "other php file on same server", you can put the data into a file on the disk...

Answer (score 0):

Write the data in file 
1- plain text
2- Json text (json encode and decode required for this)

What ever type you need you can do and other page you can read the data and display

Answer (score 0):

By removing those methods you've essentially written off temporary storage/data transfer methods.

All I can suggest is either writing to a database and retrieving on subsequent steps (without a cookie or session you'd need to think up some way of knowing who's data is who's), or alternatively writing to a file on disk (with similar issues if expecting multiple users).